# Exact same url with Axios does not fire

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm using React and Redux with Axios. The exact same component with the exact same variables are being called from two different places in my app. One fires to my API just as expected but the other never reaches the backend. I have no idea how this is possible. They both reach my Redux action with the exact same URL so how can this be?

Button inside component:

```
<button
  onClick={e => {
    // Same button used for both
    e.stopPropagation();
    deletePost({ _id, postType, isMainPost });
  }}>
  Delete
</button>
```

action:

```
export const deletePost = ({ _id, postType }) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    // Reaches here just fine for both with exact same url
    const url = `${postType}/${_id}`;
    console.log('OUTPUT: url', url); 
    const res = await axios.delete(`api/posts/${url}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

backend api:

```
router.delete('/:postType/:_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Only one reaches here...
    const { _id, postType } = req.params;
    console.log('OUTPUT: _id', _id);
    console.log('OUTPUT: postType', postType);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is the output of this log `console.log('OUTPUT: url', url);` the same for both actions?

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the issue between the backend and frontend? 

You could use a test get request to test: Example: `https://httpbin.org/get`